# jQuery fade function with setInterval function

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, fade

I'm creating simple slide with jQuery and its work fine i just want to use fade function as well with below code. I used fade function but it's working it's not fading an image while change.

```
var mainImage = $('#mainImage');
var imageData = ['_images/gallery/beach_houses.jpg','_images/gallery/golden_gate.jpg','_images/gallery/red_rock_01.jpg'];
var imageIndex = 0;
function imageSlide(){
    mainImage.fadeIn("slow",function(){
        mainImage.attr("src",imageData[imageIndex]);
        imageIndex++;
        if(imageIndex >= imageData.length){
          imageIndex = 0;
        }
    });
}
setInterval(imageSlide,1000);
```

Comment: Please specify your expected behaviour vs the actual behaviour.  "I just want to use fade function" doesn't really explain what you're trying to achieve.  It appears you already are using `.fadeIn` (albeit incorrectly).

Comment: I'm useing fade function but it's not working kindly check and let me know why it's not working my friend

Comment: 1st time imageSlide is called, it will fade *in*.  If it's already visible, this will do nothing.  Even if it was not visible, it will fade in and *then* change the `src` - ie after the image has already been shown.   Try this:  `mainImage.fadeOut("slow", function() { $(this).attr("src",imageData[imageIndex]); $(this).fadeIn("slow") }`  (add your imageindex fix as well)

Comment: thanks i have got logic as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've used `fadeIn` already, but in order for the image fade *in* it has to be hidden, the easiest way is to fade it *out* first.

Using the fadeOut callback, you can wait for the fadeOut to complete, set the src and then fadeIn:

```
var mainImage = $('#mainImage');
var imageData = ['_images/gallery/beach_houses.jpg','_images/gallery/golden_gate.jpg','_images/gallery/red_rock_01.jpg'];
var imageIndex = 0;
function imageSlide() {

    // fade out before changing src
    mainImage.fadeOut("fast", function(){
        mainImage.attr("src",imageData[imageIndex]);
        imageIndex++;
        if(imageIndex >= imageData.length){
          imageIndex = 0;
        }

        // fade back in after changing src
        mainImage.fadeIn("slow");
    });
}

// Increase interval to provide enough time if needed
setInterval(imageSlide, 1000);
```

Note that `"slow"` = 600ms so 2x slow (fade out then in) will be longer than your setInterval of 1000ms and will create some crazy results.

Answer (score 1):

See my code follow 3 step, hope this can help you!

1. You need hide `mainImage` before use fadeIn
2. You need find target image source and set to `mainImage`
3. When you got all data needed, you can fadeIn your image at this step

Note: Index of the last item in your array is `imageData.length - 1`, reset `imageIndex` to zero here

```js
var mainImage = $('#mainImage');
var imageData = ['http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/images/a/a9/Example.jpg','http://www.buzzlinestravel.co.uk/images/itinerary/1-1276781550ufzx.jpg','http://images.all-free-download.com/images/wallpapers_large/poppies_and_coreopsis_wallpaper_flowers_nature_wallpaper_1542.jpg'];
var imageIndex = 0;
function imageSlide(){
    //1. you need hide before use fadeIn
    mainImage.hide();
    //2. you need find target source to show
    mainImage.attr("src",imageData[imageIndex]);
    imageIndex++;
    if(imageIndex === imageData.length - 1){
        imageIndex = 0;
    }
    //3. the last step, you got all data needed, you can fadeIn your image here
    mainImage.fadeIn("slow");
}
setInterval(imageSlide,1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
</head>

<body>
    
<img src="" alt="" id="mainImage">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the code below.For production purposes you still gonna have to 'polish' it.Good luck

```js
var mainImage = $('#mainImage');
var imageData = ['https://www.maxcdn.com/blog/blog-assets/2016/01/firefox-subresource-integrity-error.png','https://www.typesettercms.com/data/_addondata/x_Addons/screenshots/5/245/thumbnail.png','https://cdn9.gaborszathmari.me/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/when-the-cdn-goes-bananas-cover.png'];
var imageIndex = 0;
function imageSlide(){
    mainImage.attr("src",imageData[imageIndex]).fadeIn(1000,function(){
        imageIndex++;
        if(imageIndex >= imageData.length){
          imageIndex = 0;
        }
        setTimeout(function(){
            mainImage.fadeOut(1000,function(){
                 imageSlide();
            });
        },1000);
    });
}
imageSlide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img style="display:none;" id="mainImage">
```